# Error in customizing Search Model in Yii Framework

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm very very new to **Yii** & creating a web application that deals with **Users** & **Groups** with Yii advanced app framework.
Currently I have finished all database part & creating models & **CRUD operations** with the gii tool.

**Here is my related databases** (`user_group.group_owner_id ----> user.id`)
[image]

---

**Problem :**
When I navigate to User groups page it shows all the groups of all the users.
but I want to show only the groups that he made.

So I customized the `UserGroupSearch` model as follows, but it throws a syntax error.

---

**UserGroupSearch.php**

```
public function search($params)
{
    $current_logged_user_id = Yii::$app->user->identity->id; //get the id of the current user

    $query = UserGroup::find()->where(['group_owner_id' = $current_logged_user_id]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $this->load($params);

    //other codes
}
```

---

**Error :**

> PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'

error line number shows as the line with with the `where clause`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where(['group_owner_id' = $current_logged_user_id])`

need change to

`where(['group_owner_id' => $current_logged_user_id])`